# AngularJS - implementing "undo" with angular.copy fails

Tags: javascript, object, angularjs

Following issue: Let's say, we have an object like this:

```
$scope.Something = { 'a' : { object... }, 'b' : { another object... } }
```

This Something-object is also rendered in the view as follows:

```
<div ng-repeat="s in Something">{{ Something[s].someProperty }}</div>
```

The user wants to edit **Something.a**. For this, we show him a form. Before the form is shown, I save the current **Something.a** as a copy:

```
$scope.copyForUndo= angular.copy($scope.Something.a);
```

Now, if the user clicks "Cancel", it gets:

```
$scope.Something.a = angular.copy($scope.copyForUndo);
```

But since then, the association seems to disappear. No matter, what changes the user now makes to Something.a, the view doesn't get updated.

Why?

I know, what the equality of objects is (for example, that **{ object1: true } != {object1 : true}** but still I cannot understand, why it doesn't work.

Comment: could you share your fiddle please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can make `$scope.Something` an array, then you can edit the copy and then update the array when the changes are saved.  It still provides an undo, but in reverse of how you presented it.

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GYeSZ/1/

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {
    $scope.Something = [
        { name: "Aye", desc: new Date() },
        { name: "Bee", desc: new Date() },
        { name: "See", desc: new Date() }
    ];

    $scope.edit = function(idx) {
        $scope.copy = angular.copy($scope.Something[idx]);
        $scope.idx = idx;
    }

    $scope.save = function() {
        $scope.Something[$scope.idx] = angular.copy($scope.copy);
        $scope.cancel();
    }

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $scope.copy = null;
        $scope.idx = -1;
    }
}
```

**Update**
There is an alternate syntax for `ng-repeat` that can be used to enumerate dictionaries to get their key.  Using this syntax, you can use the data structure you describe in the question

fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/GYeSZ/3/

```
function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.edit = function(key) {
        $scope.copy = angular.copy($scope.Something[key]);
        $scope.key = key;
    }

    $scope.Something = {
        "a": { name: "Aye", desc: new Date() },
        "b": { name: "Bee", desc: new Date() },
        "c": { name: "See", desc: new Date() }
    };

    $scope.save = function() {
        $scope.Something[$scope.key] = angular.copy($scope.copy);
        $scope.cancel();
    }

    $scope.cancel = function() {
        $scope.copy = null;
        $scope.key = null;
    }
}
```

**Html**

`<div ng-repeat="(key, value) in Something" ....>`

Comment: Ok, this solution is working perfectly. The problem is only, my software is very complicated right now and I would really need to implement this in the way I proposed. Does anybody understand, how objects are saved and referenced in JavaScript? But if it all Fails, I will do it your way. +1 for this very good answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If the copy source is ng-repeat iterative item, you should use

```
angular.copy($scope.copyForUndo, $scopy.sourceItem)
```

insteads of

```
$scope.sourceItem = angular.copy($scope.copyForUndo)
```

Otherwise, your data-binding dom is not tracking because the `$$hashkey` of
the iterative item was erased by the misuse copy statement.

https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/g3_v1_2/src/Angular.js#L777

Answer (score 1):

it seems a bit odd but if you can save the original array $scope.Something then on canceling you can rebind it.

```
 // saving original array to get the original copy of edited object
 var originalArrayCopy = angular.copy($scope.Something);
 ............
 // When user clicks cancel then simply filter the originalArray to get the original copy, here i am assuming there is a field in object which can uniquely identify it. 
// var originalObject = originalArrayCopy .filter(function(elm)
   {
       if(editedObject.Id == elm.Id)
              return elm;
   } );
 // once i get the original object , i can rebind it to the currentObject which is being edited.
```

Answer (score 1):

Non destructive form editing: http://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-angular-copy-for-deep-copy

Synopsis:

- create a pointer to the object that the user clicked edit
- create a copy of object that user edits and can decide to save|cancel

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it has to do with the fact that you are copying a copy, or what, but here is a working plunker

[Copy Example Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Te0kMc?p=preview)